# Using .png as label icon

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, imaging

I created a small program which ran great, I then needed to add a GUI so ported all my code over using NetBeans to make things a bit easier. Ive got it working great when I use jpgs but obviously that isnt the best format to use. Before, when I used pngs it worked fine, now I get a big list of errors in the console which I never would get before.
Essentially the program reads the file the user selects as a bufferedimage and it also sets the label in the GUI as the selected file, or it did until creating the GUI. As I say it works fine with jpg, no issues at all so im not too sure what is happening. Its also reading it as a bufferedimage fine as im printing the filepath and bufferedimage variable to the console so can see both of those are fine, then a big list of errors which are the following:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [I cannot be cast to [B   at
>   java.awt.image.ColorModel.getAlpha(ColorModel.java:833)   at
>   java.awt.image.ColorModel.getRGB(ColorModel.java:878)     at
>   sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.convertToRGB(ImageRepresentation.java:305)
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.setPixels(ImageRepresentation.java:564)
>     at
>   java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter.accumPixels(AreaAveragingScaleFilter.java:213)
>     at
>   java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter.setPixels(AreaAveragingScaleFilter.java:252)
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.sendPixels(OffScreenImageSource.java:102)
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.produce(OffScreenImageSource.java:187)
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.addConsumer(OffScreenImageSource.java:66)
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.startProduction(OffScreenImageSource.java:80)
>     at
>   java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource.startProduction(FilteredImageSource.java:183)
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.startProduction(ImageRepresentation.java:727)
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.drawToBufImage(ImageRepresentation.java:802)
>     at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(DrawImage.java:1018)     at
>   sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.copyImage(ValidatePipe.java:186)     at
>   sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3084)   at
>   sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(SunGraphics2D.java:3069)   at
>   javax.swing.ImageIcon.paintIcon(ImageIcon.java:413)   at
>   sun.swing.plaf.synth.SynthIcon.paintIcon(SynthIcon.java:67)   at
>   javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthGraphicsUtils.paintText(SynthGraphicsUtils.java:396)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLabelUI.paint(SynthLabelUI.java:213)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLabelUI.update(SynthLabelUI.java:177)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1512)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1443)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

---

With my code for loading the icon being:

```
image1 = ImageIO.read(file);            
            ImageIcon imageIcon1 = new ImageIcon(image1);
            Image redInput = imageIcon1.getImage().getScaledInstance(300, 300, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            imageIcon1.setImage(redInput);
            redLabel.setIcon(imageIcon1);
```

I only have 1 class called `NewJFrame`, any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Going to hard to diagnose without some code...

Comment: Yeah sorry just thought that myself, edited the post

Comment: Are you trying to paint the image your self?  Can you provide an example PNG?

Comment: It's a satellite image which was originally in tiff format but I converted it to png, so possibly its an issue due to the encoding? Theres not much on the internet about it apart from it potentially being a Mac specific problem and I am using a Mac

Comment: You may need to reduce the color palette...

Comment: I had to convert it to RGB from indexed before saving as a png, obviously with jpg you dont need to. A silly error from me!

Comment: Not that it matters to the problem, but why are you doing your work so complicated, first creating the icon with the unscaled image, then getting the same image back from the icon, scaling it and setting it again on the icon? Why not: loading the image, scaling the image and *then* creating the `ImageIcon`?

Comment: What JRE (vendor/version/platform) are you on? This seems like a bug in the JRE libraries, deep down in the AWT internals... From the stack trace and the fact that it works with JPEG, it looks you could work around the problem by converting your `BufferedImage`s from `TYPE_INT_something` to `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` or similar. But that's speculation of course. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn’t seem to be an error in your code, I suggest to try to work-around this problem as you can’t change the AWT implementation.

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(file);
Image redInput=new AffineTransformOp(
  AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(300.0/img.getWidth(), 300.0/img.getHeight()),
  AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC).filter(img, null);
imageIcon1= new ImageIcon(redInput, file.toString());
redLabel.setIcon(imageIcon1);
```

This code goes to a different path dedicated to the specialized processing of a `BufferedImage`. There’s no guaranty the this doesn’t encounter the same bug (as I hadn’t have your file to test it). But I think, it’s worth a try as the change to your code is rather small.

If that doesn’t work you can try the to convert the color space manually right after loading as already suggested by others:

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(file);
final int w = img.getWidth(), h = img.getHeight();
BufferedImage bi=new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
bi.setRGB(0, 0, w, h, img.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w), 0, w);
img=bi;
// proceed as normally
```

Comment: Im not too sure what this code is doing but when I try to use it I get a bunch of errors on every line so I think ill give it a miss! Thanks anyway

Comment: What kind of errors? You have to import `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform` and `java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp` and you should be willing to *really try* it instead of giving up without any attempt. And you should get familiar with the concept of studying documentation. Every class and method used in the code above is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html

Comment: I dont know what the code you posted is doing though or how its different to my original code which works perfectly fine for me. Is this way more effective?
I was getting errors because of variables but I have fixed it now, I still get the same error in the original post when I try to import the old pngs.

Comment: @user2517280 It does the same thing your code did but using a different way. It uses the same variable names as your code does. I can’t magically insert more variable declarations than you have shown in your own code example.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to cast an `int[]` to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Strange, any idea why this is happening only when I choose a png instead of a jpg?

Comment: @user2517280 After looking at the code you provided, I'm not sure. Are you sure you don't have any other pieces of code throughout your program that might cause this behaviour? Generally speaking, if you didn't have any other possible conflicting code, I don't see anything wrong with your code.